# File picker with ability to select folder to be used on a webpage

Tags: html, filepicker

Basically what we need is an filepicker that can be used on a webpage to enable the user to select files and/or folders. BUT, we only need to be able to get the local (client side) filepaths for the selected files via javascript, to later be used with another fileupload applet. So the upload upload part is no problem, just the file picker part.

So is there any available crossplatform/browser components available (that can be skinned), or do we have to create a custom one in java? Or is there a smarter way to go?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily using the "input" html tag with type set to "file". Read [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#file-select) article from w3.org.

Thanks,
Vamyip

Comment: You missed the crucial part: "and/or folders" :)

Answer (score -1):

Browsers cannot handle folders themselves. You need to use Flash or Java to do this.

Comment: Yes, I know that. That why Im asking if there's any alreday made components ready to be reused or if we need to make it ourselfes. :)