# Browsing file system to select directory in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

is there a way to implement browsing file system directory in facelets
i don't want the user to type the directory 
i search it in primefaces showcases but i didn't find it .

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: For what purpose? File uploading?

Comment: @Gnappuraz no just for choosing a path of a directory which will be saved in database for example  (c:\dir)

Comment: Browsing client side or server side? Please be more specific.

Comment: @siebz0r browsing client machine file system ti choose a directory path .Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons you cannot browse the filesystem with HTML/JavaScript. If you want to do such a thing you could use a Java applet or a Flash element, but I found such things repulsive.

The reason you want to do this is unclear to me. If it's for downloading a file and selecting a destination, you should be using a regular file download.

You might want to do more research. I found a couple questions on SO that are comparable:

- [Directory Chooser in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809688/directory-chooser-in-html-page)
- [File picker with ability to select folder to be used on a webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155087/file-picker-with-ability-to-select-folder-to-be-used-on-a-webpage)
- [How can I let the user select a folder from an HTML page so that all the files can be uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074739/how-can-i-let-the-user-select-a-folder-from-an-html-page-so-that-all-the-files-c)

Comment: JSF has `<h:inputFile...>`.  @AmiraGL is asking if there is such thing as `<h:inputDir...>`.