# How to download a json file from Primeface app using GSON?

Tags: java, json, primefaces, download, gson

I need to dowload a file `.json` from my application, but to choose its location.

- I know how to download a file to disk, like for an image `<p:fileDownload value=""/>`

  ```
  public StreamedContent getFile(){
      return new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "image/jpg", "img.jpg"); 
  }
  ```
- I know how to write to file with `GSON` with given path

  ```
  try(JsonWrite j = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                            new FileOutputStream("C:\\...\\...\\file.json"), "UTF-8"))){
     j.beginObject();
     // ...
     j.name("foo");
     gson.toJson(myObj, Foo.class, j);
     //...
     j.endObject();
  }catch(...){...}
  ```

But I do not know how to combine both to be able to choose the location and write the json at this location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I don't think you can do what you want.  All you can do is stream your JSON file and give it a name like "test.json".  For security reasons you are not allowed to tell the browser WHERE you want the user to download.  I believe it is similar to this request: [Browsing file system to select directory in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881943/browsing-file-system-to-select-directory-in-jsf)

If however you just want to send a GSON file allowing the user to download it.

**XHTML:**

```
<p:fileDownload value="#{myController.downloadFile()}" />
```

**JAVA:**

```
public StreamedContent downloadFile() {
      // convert GSON object to InputStream
      String gson= json.getJSONObject("data").toString();
      InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(gson.getBytes());

      DefaultStreamedContent  content = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream,
                  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
                  "test.json");

      return content;
   }
```

Comment: I only found "MediaType.Application_JSON" in https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MediaType.html

Comment: Yep that was a typo on my part. Fixed my post.